# Stop Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update on pod install

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.1.1

how do i stop the re-installing of old pods on new pod install.

old pod was 1.0.0, updated pod is 1.1.1

> pod install --no-repo-update ---->
>   Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update.
>
> for example:
>   pod file: pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.3'
>
> Installing Alamofire (3.5.1) --> prevent this from installing on pod install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a specific version, don't use compatibility operator `~>`, just provide the version:

`pod 'Alamofire', '3.3.1'`

This means that you only want this, and no other version. By specifying `'~> 3.3'`, you are saying that you want any version that's compatible, which essentially is `3.x.y`.
You can read more on semantic versioning here: http://semver.org.

Comment: well the answer is correct, but it still is installing the same old pod library, and i dont know currently which version am using in 3.x.x. is there any way to only install the new library without touching the old library?

Comment: Check `Podfile.lock` to figure out which version you are currently using. Also if you check in `Podfile.lock` into your repository, `pod install` won't actually install anything new, it'll pull cached version of the library, which should make no change and is fast.

Comment: Correct, it should have not installed, i didn't had this problem on previous pod version, i guess due to update of pod to 1.1.1 from 1.1.0 made this major version update? I guess its not accessing the cached versions.